# Module not found: Can't resolve 'watson-react-components'

Tags: reactjs, components, ibm-cloud, jsx, watson

I try to run a REACT application on bluemix / IBMCloud which runs successful on my local workstation.

I get the error Module not found: Can't resolve 'watson-react-components'
when I invoke the application (deploy to bluemix is successful)
Here the import statement im my java script code

```
import React from 'react';
import './Conversation.css';
import { InputWithButton } from 'watson-react-components';
import Message from './Message.js';
```

I install the packagethe following install commands

```
# Install & build
npm install && npm install watson-react-components && npm run build
```

this is what I get during the installation of the packages

```
│ └── whatwg-fetch@2.0.3 
└─┬ watson-react-components@0.6.16 
  ├── map-range@0.1.2 
  ├── numeral@2.0.6 
  ├─┬ prismjs@1.11.0 
  │ └─┬ clipboard@1.7.1 
  │   ├─┬ good-listener@1.2.2 
  │   │ └── delegate@3.2.0 
  │   ├── select@1.1.2 
  │   └── tiny-emitter@2.0.2
```

Here the error message on the app

```
 Failed to compile
 ./src/Conversation.js
 Module not found: Can't resolve 'watson-react-components' in   '/home/vcap/app/src'
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry sorry --- the problem was sitting in front of the computer. I missed the cf push command in the deployment script.
Problem solved!!! sorry again

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in the command to install the app.

It should be `npm install && npm install --save watson-react-components && npm run build`

You forgot a `--save`